# Como puedo mostrar un modal o un alert en pantalla completa llamando desde un frame

Tags: html, modal

suponiendo que tengo el siguiente codigo;

```
    <frameset rows="100,*">
    <frame id="frmSuperior" name="frmSuperior" src="03_frames_pagina1.html" />

    <frameset cols="150,*">
        <frame id="frmIzquierda" name="frmIzquierda" src="03_frames_pagina2.html" />
        <frame id="frmCuerpo"    name="frmCuerpo"    src="03_frames_pagina3.html" />
    </frameset>

    <noframes>
        <body>Su navegador no soporta frames</body>
    </noframes>
</frameset>
```

Quiero llamar mostrar un modal presionando un boton que esta dentro de un frame, pero se muestra solamente en ese frame y quiero que se vea en pantalla completa, lo mismo sucede si pruebo con un SweetAlert.

Creo que deberia colocar el modal en la pagina principal y llamarlo desde el frame, pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Nunca he utilizado el Frameset pero al parecer tiene un marco, margen y es muy probable como ya lo has constatado que el modal se queda dentro de donde lo estés invocando.  Si estas desarrollando en PHP , quizás sea conveniente que desde el botón con el que haces la petición del modal lo asocies con un archivo y en este archivo tengas tu modal. Es muy probable que requieras tambien jscript para enviar datos.

Comment: Deberian quitar lo de los frameset, es antediluviano y ya no está recomendada para nada: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset